# Action Bar Hidden in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, tabs

I am building an app that has 3 pages to display. To do so, I'm using a tabbed activity.

My tabbed activity works fine with textviews, buttons, etc. By works fine I mean that I can see the tabs bar at all times and can navigate between tabs.

Now, I'm trying to populate a listview within one of the tabs. This listview uses custom rows I built. I am populating this listview upon launch using an arraylist and an adapter then displaying it.

Now, the problem is that whenever the listview populates the page using my custom rows(routelistingrow.xml), the list view immediately takes over the activity full screen and covers the tabs bar and the app is stuck in this listview.

I then tried doing these steps using a basic activity (without any tabs) just to see if the listview would stay in the right place and avoid taking control of the screen. And this worked, the action bar was always visible.

So the problem is when I try to display this listview among one of many pages.

I used this video for the tabs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ediklbippkA

I also tried using fragments within a navigation drawer rather than tabs and still got the same problem.

So I would like to know what's causing this problem and why the listview acts this way when I try to populate it from main.

I also found that this problem occurs when I try to dynamically add rows upon a button click

I left my Main2Activity as default and added the following:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 setContentView(R.layout.tab_routelistings);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.routelistingslistview);
        dataModels= new ArrayList<>();

        dataModels.add(new RouteTemplate("Canada", "USA"));
        dataModels.add(new RouteTemplate("USA", "Canda"));
        dataModels.add(new RouteTemplate("Canada", "USA"));
        dataModels.add(new RouteTemplate("USA", "Canda"));        
        dataModels.add(new RouteTemplate("Canada", "USA"));
        dataModels.add(new RouteTemplate("USA", "Canda"));


    adapter = new RouteAdapter(dataModels, getApplicationContext());



        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
 //i only added the switch statement within this method found in main2activity.

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

            switch(position)
            {
                case 0:
                    TabRouteListings tabRouteListings =  new TabRouteListings();
                    return tabRouteListings;
                case 1:
                    TabCreateRoute tabCreateRoute =  new TabCreateRoute();
                    return tabCreateRoute;
                default:
                    TabRouteListings tabRouteListings2 =  new TabRouteListings();
                    return  tabRouteListings2;

            }
        }
```

**TabCreateRoute.java**

```
public class TabCreateRoute extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_createroute, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**TabRouteListings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/routelistingslistview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**routelistingrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtstartaddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Start Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtendaddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtstartaddress"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="End Address"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <!--<Button-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:text="Modify"-->
            <!--android:textColor="@android:color/black"-->
            <!--android:textStyle="bold" />-->


        <!--<Button-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:text="Delete"-->
            <!--android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton"-->
            <!--android:textColor="@android:color/black"-->
            <!--android:textStyle="bold" />-->


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.mcgill.ecse321.driver">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've been struggling with this for the past 3 days and would like to know if I'm better off proceeding with a different method (in case you can't find a solution).

Answer (score 0):

As u mentioned ur tab view is overlapped by list view, Try below solution

U can put `android:paddingBottom= "10dp"` in root linearLayout in TabRouteListings.xml

And change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in listView in TabRouteListings.xml . This change is not directly related for ur requirement

Comment: I tried it, still no luck unfortunately. It'a not only covering the title bar but completely taking over. For example, usually, I can swipe left and right between tabs. Here, as the listview loads it restricts this swipe gesture as welll